# Flask load local json

Tags: python, json, flask

I am struggling with how to load a local json in flask.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, url_for

def taiwan():
    json_data = open(url_for('static', filename="data/taiwan.json"))
    data = json.load(json_data)
    return render_template('taiwan.jade', data=data)
```

This raises an IOError: No such file or directory: '/static/css/taiwan.json'. But it still exists.

Any suggestions

Comment: seo adds: flask load data file, flask load local file, flask open data file.

Comment: @kOssi: Can you maybe accept your own answer to mark this question as solved? This'll help future readers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, json

def showjson():
    SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static/data", "taiwan.json")
    data = json.load(open(json_url))
    return render_template('showjson.jade', data=data)
```

Comment: This may help the next guy: use `app.root_path`. It's there for this reason.

Comment: The above answer will not work if the flask is in a different directory from the web root

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically get your static directory and includes a `data` sub-dir which contains the `.json` file to load.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, current_app as app

# static/data/test_data.json
filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'data', 'test_data.json')

with open(filename) as test_file:
    data = json.load(test_file)

return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the path of Your static dir, to obtain the file, url_for gets the URI abs path, not fs path. Try this

```
json_data = open(os.path.join(your_static_dir, "data", "taiwan.json"), "r")
```